# Match object of type Module

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module, ecmascript-next

How do you match an object of type `Module` (i.e. those given when you use  dynamic  import as specified in [proposal-dynamic-import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import))

For example let's say you're going to import `foo.js`:

```
const checkWhatever = v => {
   if(v instanceof String) {

   } elseif(Array.isArray(v)) {

   } else if(v ?????) {

   }
}

import('/foo.js').then(module => {
    const output = checkWhatever(module)
})
```

For now, I could identify it by its `Symbol.toStringTag` since it returns `Module`:

```
if(v[Symbol.toStringTag] == 'Module') {
   // do stuff
}
```

Is there any way to match `Module` without using strings?

Comment: have you tried **console.log(v.__proto__.constructor.name);**

Comment: @NullPointer `Object.getPrototypeOf(m)` is `null`

Comment: maybe `typeof v == 'function'`? However, that might be too vague for your needs...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It's not a function! It's an object-like.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking if it was like `class abc {}`, then `typeof abc` returns a `function` and not an `object`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Nope, it's a native ES module

Comment: Do you have a specific usecase? It seems like treating a module general object is the best thing to do. Relying on the type seems like a poor API design.

Comment: @loganfsmyth https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-show/issues/4

Comment: @loganfsmyth more related to this: https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def/issues/218